# FASTCGI issue in IIS6 Windows server 2003

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003, fastcgi

My PHP application configured using FastCGI/IIS6/Windows server 2003.

Some times the site going to hung state, taking so much time to process the request.

That time I logged with server and checked the process in Task manager, there was so many fast_cgi.exe process are running (max 30 to 80).

I don't know why it occurring like that.below is my fast cgi settings

```
`[PHP]`
`ExePath=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe`
`InstanceMaxRequests=10000`
`ActivityTimeout=600`
`RequestTimeout=600`
`EnvironmentVars=PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS:10000,PHPRC:C:\PHP\`
```

Please advice me how to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Suresh